# Converting a list of lists in python into a mySQL table

Tags: python, mysql

Say I have 3 people and their respective attributes(height weight age) stored in a list of lists in python(calling it attr), 1 list per person.

```
    attr = [[Bob, 5.6, 140, 45], [Jay, 5.8, 150, 33], [Joe, 6.2, 180, 25]]
```

Now, I want to make attr as a table in mySQL which looks like this:

| Name | Height | Weight | Age |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | 5.6 | 140 | 45 |
| Jay | 5.8 | 150 | 33 |
| Joe | 6.2 | 180 | 25 |

So far, I have seen documentation around the INTO statement. How would I use the INTO statement for a list of lists in python such that the above table is produced in a mySQL database?

Thank you!
Umesh

Comment: The use of Python isn't particularly relevant here. You're asking something like "how do I go to the grocery store in a sedan?", where the sedan isn't generally relevant. Split your question into two parts: "how to insert these values as three rows into mysql" and "how to run a mysql query in Python". You'll find existing answers for both questions.

Answer (score 0):

Below code is for converting above in a Pandas DataFrame. That can written to written to a database (as others mentioned, split this question in parts). In below code, change **column names** as per requirement.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 
attr = [['Bob', 5.6, 140, 45], ['Jay', 5.8, 150, 33], ['Joe', 6.2, 180, 25]]

pd.DataFrame(np.vstack(attr), columns = ['col1','col2','col3','col4'])
```

Output:

[image]